# Why is this twitter bootstrap modal not working when using knockout js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I am trying to get knockout js working with a twitter bootstrap modal dialog.

I have taken the contacts editor example from the knockout js website and altered it to use a modal dialog for add/edit.

I have spent quite a while trying to make it work but for some reason it is not.

You can view it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/27pscgnk/5/

Thanks in advance for any solutions

I think the problem may be in here (this is not getting called when the user clicks save):

```
self.addContact = function() {
    self.contacts.push({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        phones: ko.observableArray()
    });
};
```

Comment: The problem isn't bootstrap, the problem is you we're referencing firstName and lastName, which are in the observable array and can only be referenced in forEach binding, try this http://jsfiddle.net/27pscgnk/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed some of the errors in the fiddle and changed the add function to work based on your input, look at the fiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/27pscgnk/6/

```
self.contact = {
    firstName: ko.observable(),
    lastName: ko.observable(),
}

self.addContact = function() {
    self.contacts.push({
        firstName: self.contact.firstName(),
        lastName: self.contact.lastName(),
        phones: ko.observableArray()
    });
};
```

and in the binding:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputNameLbl" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea data-bind="value: contact.firstName"></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputDescLbl" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea data-bind="value: contact.lastName"></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```